# Add/remove class on right click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class on right-click of an element and then remove it when anything else on the page is clicked.

I'm using jQuery.

My function is this so far:

```
$(".classElement").live('mousedown', function(e) { 
   if( (e.which == 3) ) {
     $(".classElement").addClass("active");
   }
   e.preventDefault();
}).live('contextmenu', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

However, this adds the "active" class to all ".classElement" in the doc, rather than the individual one being clicked. I want to only add the class to the element being clicked.

Also, how can I remove the class when anything else is clicked?

Comment: `$(this).addClass("active");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can removClass active on click of body element, but for this you have to stop event propagation when you are clicking on current element.

```
$(document).on('mousedown','.classElement', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  if( (e.which == 3) ) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
}).on('contextmenu','.classElement', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
$(document.body).click(function(){
  $(".classElement").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I noticed using e.preventDefault(); significantly improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this)` to target current clicked element, so you can do:

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

instead of:

```
$(".classElement").addClass("active");
```

Also, since `.live()` was removed since version `1.9`, you should use `.on()` instead.

Comment: How about removing it when anything else is clicked though?

Comment: You can put `$(".classElement").removeClass("active");` above `$(this).addClass("active");`

Answer (score 0):

to target specific element:

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

and to remove it when anything else is clicked, add this:

```
$(window).one("click", function(){
   $(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

This adds a one time only click event listener to the window.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

`$(".classElement").live('contextmenu', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
if( (e.which == 3) ) {
     $(this).addClass("active");
   }
});`
 and then remove class on document click

`$(document).click(function(){
 $(".classElement").removeClass("active");
});`